# How can I add a drawing to a pdf?

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I want the user to have a pdf with an editable field and when the user clicks on the field, it should prompt a drawing tool where he signs or draws anything he wants. When this "image" is done, it should stay inside the borders of this editable field. Is this possible using Itext?

This development will be made in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF is not meant to be a replacement for MSPaint.
So this kind of behavior is not going to be available out of the box.

**What's important to note here:**

- the PDF standard itself is working against your use-case
- iText only supports the PDF standard

**Solutions:**

- Build a PDF viewer that enables this kind of behavior (there is a company called DocuSign that implemented a similar use-case to allow users to insert their autograph in a PDF document)
- Build a plugin for a PDF viewer (e.g. Adobe Reader) that enables this kind of behavior
- (warning, *dirty hack*) insert thousands of tiny interactive components in the PDF document (PDF documents do allow interactive textboxes and checkboxes, etc). Add javascript to your PDF document to register mouse movement, and color the interactive elements based on whether the mouse moved over them or not. I doubt however that this solution would be very performant.

Comment: Thanks Joris. I'll discuss the issue with the rest of my team in order to come up with a solution based on your answer.